# Calling a jquery event after the page transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js

For instance, transitioning from `/application` to `/application/faq`, `$('.object').show();`  is set off when /application loaded, but it doesn't go off again when I transition to `application/faq`!

Maybe that's just how `didInsertElement` works, but I need something that will be called after every time I transition to anywhere with a dom element that has the class `object.

For this example, class 'object' is what I want to toggle.

```
'application_view' on didInsertElement {
   $('.object').show();
}

-'application.hbs' HTML snippet-
<div class="object"></div>

-'faq.hbs' HTML snippet-
<div class="object"></div>

all css
  .object {
   display:none
  }
```

Here's the tricky part: I want `$('.object').show();` to be activated from application_view in both `application.hbs` and `faq.hbs`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that uses jQuery to show/hide an alert as different transitions occur.  Click on "Run code snippet" to see the example.  Click on the `A`, `B`, and `C` links to transition to those routes and see the jquery animation.

```js
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('a');
  this.resource('b');
  this.resource('c');
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    willTransition: function() {
      Ember.$('.alert').fadeOut(200);
    },
    didTransition: function() {
      Ember.$('.alert').fadeIn(200);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  border: 2px #888 solid !important;
  padding: 2px 2px 3px 2px;
}
#main {
  margin: 1em;
}
.alert {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-latest.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="application">
  <div id="main">
    {{#link-to 'a'}}<span class="label label-default">A</span>{{/link-to}} {{#link-to 'b'}}<span class="label label-default">B</span>{{/link-to}} {{#link-to 'c'}}<span class="label label-default">C</span>{{/link-to}} {{outlet}}
    <div class="alert alert-success">Success!</div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Steve! When using did and willTransition, i was able to make 2 console logs appear before and after the route was loaded. However the alerts do not appear. Similarly when i try to add a class to a dom element using `$().addClass()`, no class is added

Comment: Those sound like problems not related to your question.  I'd suggest editing your question and adding more code to get more help.

Comment: how does trying to make a jquery event activate post transition different than my question 'Calling a jquery event after the page transitions'?

Comment: My assumption was that your problem was about the proper hook for executing code related to Ember transitions.  The problems you describe in your comment (and not your question) are about the use of jQuery more than when the code runs.  You didn't mention that in your question, nor did you post the code, assuming you changed it to use the `willTransition` / `didTransition` technique.

Comment: Actually it is in my question because it's the title. Second, the problems i describe in my comment are related to the didTransition function not responding to my jquery (which again, is mentioned in the title). It could be plain js or anything the manipulates the dom, that's not the point. The point is that the didTransition function is not calling jquery or even your alerts after the transition.

Comment: Without more code, I'm unable to help you any further.  Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63251/discussion-between-steve-h-and-ian-steffy).