# Why does didTransition not call my jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js

This question came to me after running into an issue with didTransition in this question. '[Calling a jquery event after the page transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368133/calling-a-jquery-event-after-the-page-transitions)'

So as you can see there is the console.log & jquery

Note that every html (or hbs since this is Ember.js) file has a class called `float-right-col` & it's important that after every transition in my application, that the '`float-right-col`' class is found and receive the class  `float-right-col-minimized`.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({   
      actions: {
         didTransition: function() {
           console.log('log2');
           $('.float-right-col').addClass('float-right-col-minimized').delay(200);
         },
      },   
});
```

&& then of course in every html/hbs file there is a div with the class `float-right-col`

```
<div class="float-right-col"></div>
```

The weird part is that the console displays the message 'log2', but the '`float-right-col`' remains untouched.

My first thought was that maybe didTransition

Comment: This should not be tagged `css`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I just removed the `css` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could definitely approach this in a much more Ember way. If you are set on using JQuery to handle this kind of logic (IMO that approach neglects some of the tools Ember provides you with), you are going to probably want to take into account the Ember Run Loop. Events in ember essentially sit on a priority queue until they are executed. The particular queue of interest is `afterRender`:

> The afterRender contains jobs meant to be run after all previously
>   scheduled render tasks are complete. This is often good for 3rd-party
>   DOM manipulation libraries, that should only be run after an entire
>   tree of DOM has been updated

So something along the lines of:

```
Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', self, function(){
    $('.float-right-col').addClass('float-right-col-minimized');
});
```

I occasionally have to write code like this when I wrap JQuery libraries in components.

But the real power of Ember is how it can take your logic out of the DOM and put the truth in the Javascript. I don't know what you are trying to do exactly, but let me throw a suggestion or two out there. Ember controller's are meant to encapsulate your templates state. If you have some css that depends on something being minimized or not, you should have a template like this:

```
<div {{bind-attr "class=isMinimized:float-right-col-minimized"}}>
 stuff
</div>
```

Then on your controller, you have a computed property or just a regular property:

```
isMinimized: true
someFunction: function(){
   if(cond)
       this.set('isMinimized', true);
   else
       this.set('isMinimized', false);
}.observes('someChangingPropertyElseWhere')
```

or

```
isMinimized: function(){
    if(cond)
         return true;
    else
         return false;
}.property('someChangingPropertyElseWhere')
```

This adds the css class `float-right-col-minimized` whenever `isMinimized` evaluates to true (use :: for adding when false).

You can also `{{bind-attr "class=dynamic :static"}}` where dynamic is the variable (just showing you the : before a class name if its just a regular class not a controller variable name). The difference here is that dynamic, instead of returning true or false like the previous example, returns the string that is the css class. eg:

```
dynamic: function(){
    if(cond)
        return 'float-right col float-right-col-minimized'
    else
        return 'float-right col'
}.property()
```

In all of these cases, your logic elsewhere changes your Javascript variables like `isMinimzed`, which in turn updates the DOM. I much prefer thinking in terms of variables like `isMinimized`, and setting this whenever something should be minimized, rather than writing JQuery selectors, worrying about when the DOM is available, etc. Feels a whole lot cleaner. Ember handles the appropriate time to rerender changes if you let it. Plus, if you need something else to depend on minimization, it can observe the `isMinimized` property. Its fairly easy to set up relationships that can cause a chain reaction of DOM updates.

And if you need this property available on every page, because you have the minimization class on every page after a transition, consider using an `Ember.Mixin`, and extend all of your controllers with it. This mixin could encapsulate the toggling of this class as well as adding the `isMinimized` property to each controller that extends the mixin.

Do you what you want, I just have found that if I have to write any JQuery when I'm not interfacing with someone elses DOM in my Ember applications, I've failed at using Ember's power to the fullest

Comment: You definitely went above and beyond for this response and I appreciate it because their are some core aspects of Ember that I have not yet grasped. So would `property('someChangingPropertyElseWhere')` be where I create the logic to have 'someFunction' trigger every time the page is triggered?